# MVC Architecture - Interaction between Model and View

Tags: model-view-controller

I was referring to some documents about MVC architecture and they have explained the interactions between model view and controller differently.

1. Some of them says that there is no interaction between model and view. The controller gather relevant data from model and the controller transfer that data to the view.
2. And some says that the controller notifies the view once some change happens in model and   then        view update itself by interacting with the model.

I want to know what is right and is there anything that I did not understand?

Comment: There is no right answer. It depends on what authors of a concrete MVC implementation thought is a good idea. MVC in ruby-on-rails is quite different from MVC in swift, for example.